# Qt Creator and Mac Finder is very slow with git repositories

Tags: macos, git, qt

I have a really big problem with the use of git + Qt-Creator + OS X.
We recently moved from our SVN repository to git. The problem is, that Qt Creator is really slow with the new git repo.
Especially when i am opening a source or header file. This makes the whole repo unusable, because I have to wait for about 10-15seconds till the file is open in the editor. Additionally the folder where the source files are, is slow in finder too...

With SVN i don't have these problems.

For Info:
- I am using a Macbook Air 2011 with a 128GB SSD.
- We are using Qt 5.0.1 and the Qt Creator version 2.6.2
- We are using Bitbucket as our hosting platform for the git repository

Thanks for your suggestions

Comment: If the folder containing the files is slow also when using Finder, has this question anything to do with Qt Creator?

Comment: The interesting thing is that if I am opening the file with xcode or Sublime it is fast as usual. But when i am exploring those files in my qt Project in qt creator it is really slow.

Comment: I guess if it is unusable, turn off scm and use command line gut